# How to resume a manual step in pipeline with gitlab api?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-auto-devops

I have a pipeline as below.

[pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu0Pp.png)

First two are automatic and the last two jobs are manual.

When I ran the curl command to run the pipeline, as below.

```
curl -X POST \
     --fail \
     -F token=TOKEN \
     -F "ref=REF_NAME" \
     -F "variables[RUN_NIGHTLY_BUILD]=true" \
     https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<id>/trigger/pipeline
```

It will run the first two.

But, the last two are for cleanup, so kept as manual.
Could anyone please share how to trigger this manual jobs using gitlab api/curl commands?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you could solve your issue, but I found this solution today, I am sharing it with you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64695279/gitlab-trigger-manual-action-via-api

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/526894)